# Create custom view switcher as Mvc4 Mobile build-in mechanism

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, view

Is it possible to create my own custom "view switcher" like MVC4 mobile does?

for example: 
If I change my view name to "_Layout.Mobile.cshtml" it'll be automatically render the view if the user-agent is mobile device.
I want to manage couple of sites in one project so I want to allow by configuration(web.config) to call the view with the same way.

for example:
Account.Project1.cshtml (if configured to project 1)
Account.Project2.cshtml (if configured to project 2)
Account.Mobile.cshtml (if called from mobile) 
Account.Project1.Mobile.cshtml (if called from mobile and project 1) 
Account.cshtml (default)

I tried to google about it but i didn't found any question about this subject.

Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn296507.aspx

Comment: You can create a custom ViewEngine per project and override `ViewLocationFormats` to locae views.For reference check http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/294297/Creating-your-own-MVC-View-Engine-into-MVC-Applica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the `DefaultDisplayMode`:

```
  public class MobileDisplay : DefaultDisplayMode
  {
    public MobileDisplay()
      // postfix of the file
      : base("mobile")
    {
      // create an expression if the current postfix is applicatble
      ContextCondition = context => context.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice;
    }
  }
```

And you can insert the in the app start:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new MobileDisplay());
```

This works like the routes and exceptions. First match win so that is why my example insert it to index 0.
The layout is not choosen by this. You can set the layout view per cshtml file or in the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file.
Of course You can set the mobile layout only in the concrete view or set in the `_ViewStart` base on logic:

```
@{
  if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
  {
    Layout = "Shared/_Layout.mobile.cshtml";
  }
  else
  {
    Layout = "Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }
}
```